# Sort Function (ascending) for Userform Listbox Excel

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, excel-2013

I am an IT enthusiast but I am not too good with programming or VBA. As a side project, I am compiling some data and would like to make it user friendly.  I am new to forums so any advice would be welcome.

I have a Userform with a Listbox which has a large list of cities, but the list is unsorted. I understand i can go into the last page where I have the country capital list connected to the Listbox and sort the column there directly in the worksheet, but that would ruin my country list, so i would like to sort the list within the Userform Listbox, is there a way to do this?

I would also like to be able to add a Userform 'find' function within the Userform itself, as I have already done so, but I am unsure how to make it work despite trying some code, I failed, if you do know, then it would be great to hear whatever kind of advice, Thank you in advance.

Please find file in the link below with an image describing objectives and the code i currently have.

File:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/d4iaui

```
Sub Listb(target)
Location.ListBox1.List = Range("countrycapital").Value

For j = 0 To Location.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   Location.ListBox1.Selected(j) = False
Next j
currentrow = target.Row
'Location.Cells(19, 2) = Sheets("Practice List").Cells(target.Row, 3)
locval = target & ","
k = 0
For i = 1 To Len(locval)
Length = Abs(k - Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(",", locval, i))
Values = Mid(locval, i, Length - 1)
For j = 0 To Location.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Location.ListBox1.List(j) = Values Then
        Location.ListBox1.Selected(j) = True
        GoTo nxt
    End If
Next j
nxt:
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(",", locval, i)
k = i
Next i
Location.Show
End Sub

Sub newlocation()
Location.ListBox1.List = Range("countrycapital").Value

For j = 0 To Location.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   Location.ListBox1.Selected(j) = False
Next j

Location.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call ThisWorkbook.checkcriteria
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim vaItems As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim vTemp As Variant

Me.ListBox1.AddItem "B"     'these new added values show on the userform
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "A"     ' instead, I would like the original Listbox1...
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "D"     ' ...incorporated within the sort function
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "C"

'Put the items in a variant array
vaItems = Me.ListBox1.List

'Steal code from John Walkenbach’s Excel Power Programming
'with VBA to sort the array
For i = LBound(vaItems, 1) To UBound(vaItems, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(vaItems, 1)
        If vaItems(i, 0) > vaItems(j, 0) Then
            vTemp = vaItems(i, 0)
            vaItems(i, 0) = vaItems(j, 0)
            vaItems(j, 0) = vTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Clear the listbox
Me.ListBox1.Clear

'Add the sorted array back to the listbox
For i = LBound(vaItems, 1) To UBound(vaItems, 1)
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem vaItems(i, 0)
Next i
End Sub



Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer,     ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
HookListBoxScroll Location, Location.ListBox1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
UnhookListBoxScroll
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a hosting site, especially not with with your code as an image.

Comment: Hello Nathan, thanks for the advice: the image is not the code, the image shows the userform and what my main objectives are.  I will post relevant code and see if you have some time to look at it.  Thanks again

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to sort range where the locations are stored?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit further?  Do you mean the data found on the worksheet cells?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents :
- in order to sort things, I usually use the .Net Sort function. Some are accessible via Com Wrapper : CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
- this object has a .Contains function, that could be use by your Find function.
Hope this helps !